# swift, Alamofire, SwiftyJSON : How to parsing arrayObject

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I don't know how can make Array using SwiftyJSON.JSON
I can parse struct using SwiftyJSON.JSON but I can't parse object-array.
Please help me.

JSON

```
{
  "result": {
    "list": [
      {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryNm": "main_1",
        "subCategoryList": [
          {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "categoryNm": "sub_1_1"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 4,
            "categoryNm": "sub_1_2"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 5,
            "categoryNm": "sub_1_3"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 6,
            "categoryNm": "sub_1_4"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 28,
            "categoryNm": "sub_1_5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 7,
        "categoryNm": "main_2",
        "subCategoryList": [
          {
            "categoryId": 9,
            "categoryNm": "sub_2_1"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 10,
            "categoryNm": "sub_2_2"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 11,
            "categoryNm": "sub_2_3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Model.swift

```
struct Model {
    public let list: Array<Category>
    public init?(json: JSON) {
        self.list = json["list"].arrayObject as! Array<Category>
    }
}

struct Category {
    public let categoryId: NSInteger
    public let categoryNm: NSString
    public let subCategoryList: Array<SubCategory>
    public init?(json: JSON) {
        self.categoryId = json["categoryId"].intValue as NSInteger
        self.categoryNm = json["categoryNm"].stringValue as NSString
        self.subCategoryList = json["subCategoryList"].arrayObject as! Array<SubCategory>
    }
}

struct SubCategory {
    public let categoryId: NSInteger
    public let categoryNm: NSString
    public init?(json: JSON) {
        self.categoryId = json["categoryId"].intValue as NSInteger
        self.categoryNm = json["categoryNm"].stringValue as NSString
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let resultModel = Model.init(json: json["result"])
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
```

I don't know how can make Array using SwiftyJSON.JSON
I can parse struct using SwiftyJSON.JSON but I can't parse object-array.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The following code parses *my.json* file into an array of Categories and SubCategories

Declare `categories` array

```
var categories = [Category]()
```

Open your file and create a `JSON` object

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "my", ofType: "json")!
let jsonData = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: path)
let json = JSON(data: jsonData! as Data)
```

Create `categories` and append them to array

```
for categoryArray in json["result"]["list"].array! {
    guard let category = Category(json: categoryArray) else { continue }
    categories.append(category)
}
print(categories)
```

Declare `Category` struct as follows

```
struct Category {
    public let categoryId: NSInteger
    public var subCategories = [SubCategory]()
    public init?(json: JSON) {
        self.categoryId = json["categoryId"].intValue as NSInteger
        self.categoryNm = json["categoryNm"].stringValue as NSString
        for subCategory in json["subCategoryList"].array! {
            subCategories.append(SubCategory(json: subCategory)!)
        }
    }
}
```